# I am trying to get the current selected item (key) from a Combobox

Tags: python, tkinter

I think I finally know how to show everyone what I am trying to do. Here is the code placing a ttk.Combobox and a ttk.Button. The Combobox is populated with the dictionary "my_act_dict" After the user selects an item from cb, I want to hit the button and get the key from the combobox.

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import ttk

my_act_dict = {'Serve': 1, 'Stock': 2, 'Board': 3}

class Screen:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("A simple GUI")
        master.geometry("200x200")

        self.save_button = ttk.Button(master, text="What is cb key?", command=self.save)
        self.save_button.pack()

        self.cb_act = ttk.Combobox(master, values=[*my_act_dict])
        self.cb_act.pack()

    def save(self):
        # cb_key = ??? 
        print("cb key = ?")
```

How do I get the Combobox key when the user presses the Button?

```
root = Tk()
my_gui = Screen(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Sorry, I have not been very clear. I am just starting learning python and am having real problems with classes.
thanks for your help.

John

Comment: what do you want the mysql query to do and why do you have a `par_per` defined when you are using `var_per`

Comment: You don't have to use `list(my_dict.keys())`. You can just do `[*my_dict]`. Also, on top of what @Cool Cloud said, you are using `my_dict` then `my_vol_dict`. It seems like your variables are all over the place. Also you don't need a `bind`. You can use `postcommand` or `validate` with `validatecommand`

Comment: You can simply use `vol_id = my_dict[var_per.get()]` to get the required id inside the callback of the button.

Comment: Yes I know I had the variables all mixed up. Sorry, I have adjusted the question. Also, thanks to Michael Guidry, removing the "list" worked.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is creating a Class attribute my_key and accessed it from both the Combobox and the Button.

```
my_dict = {'Serve': 1, 'Stock': 2, 'Board': 3}


class Screen:
    my_key = "None"

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.geometry("300x300")

    def bu_callback():
        a = self.my_key
        print("button click global: ", a)
    self.my_button = ttk.Button(master, text="Test CB RETURN",command=bu_callback)
    self.my_button.pack()

    var_per = tk.StringVar()
    cb = ttk.Combobox(master, values=[*my_dict],textvariable = var_per)
    cb.pack()

    def cb_callback(event):
        key_p = var_per.get()
        vol_id = my_dict[key_p]
        self.my_key = vol_id
        print("from cb_callback:",self.my_key)
    cb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', cb_callback)
```